# React Router blank page

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to use React Router but it keeps showing me a blank page. Here is my code:

Routering.js

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import { HashRouter as Router,Routes,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/app.js'
import Login from './components/login.js'
import NotFound from './components/NotFound.js';
const Routering = ()=> {
    <Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={Login}/>
        <Route element={NotFound}/>
        <Route exact path="/"  element={App}/>
    </Routes>
    </Router>
}
export default Routering;
```

index.js:

```js
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import React from 'react';
import  ReactDOM  from 'react-dom';
import Routering from './Routering.js';
import Login from './components/login.js';
import App from './components/app.js';
import './css/app.scss';

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render( <Routering />)
```

I am using "React Router V6", can anyone tell me what is the problem? Thanks for all the helpers.`

Comment: Blank pages are usually accompanied by error messages in your browser console. Do you have any?

Comment: change your element like this <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}/>
        <Route element={<NotFound />}/>
        <Route exact path="/"  element={<App />}/>

Answer (score 0):

In the element, you should have `<Login />` and `<App />`, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed my code to this:        
    <Route path="/login" element= <Login/> />  Is it right or not? it is not blank now but it is still not the right page. For example, when I visit /login it is still in the /app page